# How to call articles content by single category at module in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have created one category named as **cat1** and after that created four articles named **art1**, **art2**, **art3** and **art4** and assign all articles to same category.
Now my task, how can I call category **cat1** into the module so that all articles content that belongs to category cat1 shows in frontend.

Comment: When you say "a module" do you mean a Joomla module (things in boxes around the edges)? Or do you mean component (thins in the main part of the page)?  You will probably be better of asking questions like this on http://joomla.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you haven't created a module or anything of the likes?

So just use the Joomla! modules. Go to:

Extensions -> Modules -> New (Top right) -> Select: Articles - Category.

Then under the tab: Filtering Options, scroll down to: Category: and select the desired category.

The module will then show everything under that category. Or however else you configure the module to show it.

Of course, you need to set what pages and where on the page it will show.